# In Asp.Net MVC what other options do I have with Authentication Mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, client-certificates

In the Web.config file this piece of info is there

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

What other mode can I set and could I have multiple modes?

Some users could logon using username/pass, others with x509 clientCert.

Where is there some info on this?

Answer (score 3):

We can have five authentication modes in mvc ...

```
<authentication mode="Federated"></authentication>
<authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
<authentication mode="None"></authentication>
<authentication mode="Passport"></authentication>
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```